# Is this done with a regular expression? Formatting Latitude Longitude

Tags: javascript, regex, leaflet

I am trying to format a polygon (several lat/long coordinates connected together) using Leaflet Draw. Here is the format return and what I have done so far:

```
map.on("draw:drawstop", polyPointToString);              
function polyPointToString(e){
    console.log("Unaltered Coordinates: " + coords);
    polyStringParse = coords.toString().replace(/[^\d,.-]/g, '');             
    console.log("Polyparse: " + polyStringParse);
    polyStringParseRegExp = polyStringParse.replace(/([^,]+[^,]),/g,'$1 ');
    console.log("PolyparseRegExp: " + polyStringParseRegExp);
}
```

Unaltered Coordinates is this:

```
//Unaltered Coordinates: LatLng(46.58907, -102.74414),LatLng(46.58907, -102.74414),LatLng(46.58907, -102.74414)
```

PolyParse is this (only numbers, dashes, and decimal points left):

```
//Polyparse: 46.58907,-102.74414,46.58907,-102.74414,46.58907,-102.74414
```

PolyparseRegExpt is this(it keeps removing ALL commas :-(   ):

```
//Polyparse2: 46.58907 -102.74414 46.58907 -102.74414 46.58907 -102.74414
```

What is need: Comma 1, 3, 5, 7.... etc removed so that I have:

number number, number number, number number,........

Basilcally, every odd numbed comma. right now it's removing all commas for some reason.

Comment: What is `coords`, not as a string, but as an object?  Change your `console.log` to `console.log("Unaltered Coordinates: ", coords)`.  Turning an object into a string representation and then parsing that out is making this unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: coords is an array of points on a map.

Comment: I seriously think that your approach of using regexps to format this array is a form of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution (?) - add the other coordinate (preceded by *it's* comma), making it a pair, capturing it separately **without** the comma:

```
([^,]+[^,]),([^,]+[^,],)
```

replacing it with

`$1 $2` (space between and trailing)

reforms the coordinate pair, without the separating comma but leaving the trailing.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/s2cBD8/4).

Comment: Hey ClasG. Thanks, but that seems to be removing the even numbered commas. I need first, third, fifth,.. etc.  Regex101 looks cool though. Did not know that existed.

Comment: Sorry about that. Read it sloppily ;) Fixed.

Comment: Excellent! RegEx is still somewhat of a mystery to me (just learned of its existence yesterday). I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as accepted answer (important since it makes it easier for people with similar problems to find) and if you find it useful - upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `coords` is an array of [Leaflet's `LatLng`s](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#latlng). Using `toString()` is an odd thing to do, considering that you can use `.lat` and `.lng` to access the `LatLng`'s properties.

It also looks like you're trying to convert your data into WKT (Well-Known-Text) due to yur use of spaces and commas.

So you can convert a `LatLng` into a WKT coordinate pair with something like:

```
var latlng = L.latLng(...)
var wktPoint = latlng.lng + ' ' + latlng.lat;
```

And, if you have an array of `LatLng`s, you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to great effect here:

```
var coords = [ L.latLng(...), L.latLng(...), ... ];

var wktLineString = coords.map(function(ll){
    // For every item in the array, return a string.
    // The call to .map() will thus return an array of strings
    return ll.lng + ' ' + ll.lat;

    // Once the array of strings is ready, join those strings
    // with the given separator.
}).join(',');
```

As I'm assuming you're using WKT, note the swapping of the coordinates so you can have lng-lat instead of lat-lng. Also note you can use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and the like to have better control of the output.